# How to explode json data already present in mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database-connection

I have a `database table` which previously had a coloumn `data` having a json data in it

```
| data |  - `"{"display":{"pageName":"TEBT Home","Name":"rtryrtyrty rtyrtyrtyrty",
               "Email":"trupti.gjklhjkgv@gmail.com","state":"WB","city":"CTY_ARAM",
               "dob":"09/12/1964"}}"`
```

now I want to restructure my data_table and add different coloumns for pageName , Name, Email, state, city, dob and want to exlpode the json data already present in 'data' coloumn.

**this is the logic I am trying to Implement , but it doesn't work .**

```
<?php

$dataString = "SELECT data FROM data_table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $dataString);
$data =array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $data[] = $row['data'];
}
$iterations = ceil(count($data));

for ($x = 0; $x <$iterations; $x++) {

    echo "The number is: ".$x." <br>";
    if (!empty($data)) { 

    $json = json_decode($data, true);

    $page = $json['display']['pageName'];
    $name = $json['display']['Name'];
    $email =$json['display']['Email'];
    $mob =$json['display']['mobno'];
    $state =$json['display']['state'];
    $city =$json['display']['city'];
    $dob =$json['display']['dob'];

    echo $page;

    $sql = "UPDATE data_table SET page = '".$page."' WHERE data ='".$data."' ";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    } 

    else 
    {
        echo "done";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: What does not work? Any error messages? Please provice more information

Comment: is echo $page is showing the data which you want and you are using echo "done" in else so don't wait for that. Your code will not display anything neither on success nor on failure

Comment: there is no error as such but it doesnot segregate the json in the database coloumns that i have created , and echo $page shows output as "Array"

Comment: try var_dump($json); in place of echo $page; so you will have idea of your data and it will help you more

Answer (score 0):

use this code to see db error if any :

```
$dataString = "SELECT data FROM data_table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $dataString);
$data =array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $data[] = $row['data'];
}
$iterations = ceil(count($data));

for ($x = 0; $x <$iterations; $x++) {


       echo "The number is: ".$x." <br>";

 if (!empty($data)) { 

$json = json_decode($data, true);

$page = $json['display']['pageName'];
$name = $json['display']['Name'];
$email =$json['display']['Email'];
$mob =$json['display']['mobno'];
$state =$json['display']['state'];
$city =$json['display']['city'];
$dob =$json['display']['dob'];

echo $page;


$sql = "UPDATE data_table SET page = '".$page."' WHERE data ='".$data."' ";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con)); // added to see error msg
    }
```